# Server load with Nodemailer in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Nodemailer allows users to send emails to my gmail client. I would like to know the chances of my node server crashing for example if users were to spam the "submit" button on the contact form. I remember spamming the submit button on the contact form and it almost crashed my node server (severely slowed down the server). Can I please get some advice on how I could go about preventing such a thing? Do I have to code a specific feature on top of Nodemailer? I tried form validation but don't think it is suffice. Any advice? Cheers

Comment: Why would it crash your server?  You need to understand what exactly is harming your server and then and only then can you devise a plan to protect your server from that.

Comment: It is because of time it takes to send one email in Nodemailer (3 or 4 seconds). So if the user spammed the submit button 10 times the server will slow down by miles (maybe not crash).

Comment: If something slowed down your server, it could be some blocking code. If you can't find it, you can at least put a rate-limiting middleware just before your contact form API, in order to avoid "spamming". But, of course, you'd better debug your code first.

Comment: Nodemailer should be async so an operation that takes 3 to 4 seconds to complete should only be using a lot less CPU time than that.  If it's not async, then you need to throw it away or put it in another dedicated process because synchronous I/O will ruin the responsivness of any node.js server.  Or perhaps you are using it wrongly.  Honestly, we can't really do much when you don't show your code.